# Copy image from document directory to photos library in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, nsdocumentdirectory

I am having a string array of names of images stored in the document directory of the application.
I want to Copy images from the document directory of the application to the PHOTOS LIBRARY OF DEVICE.

Comment: This isn’t even a question, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Swift 4**

*I will tell you the steps to save a photo from Document] -> [Photos Library] in the easiest way that is using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum() function of UIKit*

Step 1:

- Ask for permission to access Photos Library “Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description”
- Refer to this link for more details
  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/delivering_an_enhanced_privacy_experience_in_your_photos_app

Step 2:

- Get the [image data] you want to copy with Data(contentsOf: URL)
- You can learn how to get the [Url] of the file in the [Document], do a search because this job has a lot of articles and is also very easy to do. Dont worried

Step 3:

- Create a [UIImage] from the [Data] you got above

Step 4:

- Pass the [UIImage] present in step 3 to the first parameter of UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(). All remaining parameters can be set to nil.